# Error with calling a cpp function from another cpp function

Tags: c++

```
I've created three files namely test.cpp, function.h and function.cpp in a folder. test.cpp contains this code : 

#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "function.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    freopen ("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen ("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    int a,b;
    cin >> a >> b;

    cout << add(a,b) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

function.h contains this code:

```
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int add(int a,int b);
```

function.cpp contains this code:

```
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int add(int a,int b);

int add(int a,int b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

This produces some error which says reference in add(int,int) is undefined. Here is the error message:

/tmp/ccbx3TEZ.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to`add(int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 2.0s with exit code 1]

Please, suggest me what to do.

Comment: be sure you link the function.cpp. Besides, int add(int a,int b); the preceded declaration should only be in header, not also in source.

Comment: Additionaly, function.cpp does not include function.h

Comment: In addition to the duplicate which will explain what exactly such linking errors mean and how to fix them, please also read [why you should not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/1782465) and why [`using namespace std;` is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1782465)

Comment: You should show us the exact command you use to compile - and crucially, link - those sources.  It looks a lot like you've simply missed `function.o` from your link command.